# What is the impact of a dummy variables to boosted trees?

Tags: random-forest, boosting, cart, categorical-encoding

I am currently reading the book "Random Forests" by Yu. L. Pavlov. Then it came across my mind the question If I were to use ensembled tree, say XGBOOST, do I need to transform each categorical variable into a dummy variable.

I have searched the internet and found mixed results
People saying that dummy variables impacts performance: [article 1](https://towardsdatascience.com/one-hot-encoding-is-making-your-tree-based-ensembles-worse-heres-why-d64b282b5769), [article 2](https://roamanalytics.com/2016/10/28/are-categorical-variables-getting-lost-in-your-random-forests/).

but majority of the articles I have read agrees with the notion that categorical variables needs to be encoded.

I would like to hear your thoughts on this, and if you can also point to any journal article tackling this matter, that would be a very huge help.

Answer (score 2):

I would dummy it up but it kind of depends, for example years of education and predicting income.  You can and should dummy it in a normal linear regression but for a tree it makes sense to leave it because the tree can learn the highschool/bachelor/master/phd splits which are more important than average incremental differences between each year.  So you are safer to use un-dummied data if there is that underlying relationship.  But if there is no underlying relationship and for example they are just ids like product 3, 4, 5 it will bucket them as if there is a relationship OR the tree will spend a lot of it's splits just splitting on the product id anyway so obviously you are better off creating dummies.  So I would say it is entirely problem/variable dependent.  And for boosted trees lightgbm typically does a lot better with loads of sparse dummies in terms of both speed and accuracy over xgboost, so just try dummies and hand it off to lightgbm and iterate from there.